# java nested loop after reading from file

Tags: java

I have an array

`arr[] = {"a", "b", "c"}`

and a text file below

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

i want to write a loop that will produce below

```
1
2
3
4
5
Hello from a
1
2
3
4
5
Hello from b
1
2
3
4
5
Hello from c
```

below is what i tried

```
String a;
for (int i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {         
while (a = br.readLine() ){

    fileWriter.write(a + "\n")
}
fileWriter.write("Hello from "  + arr[i] +"\n");
}
```

What i got is...

```
1
2
3
4
5
Hello from a
Hello from b    
Hello from c
```

Comment: You have to go back to the beginning of the file, or story the file in memory and read from it again. As it is, `br` is pointing to the end of the file, so there is no more to read.

Comment: When learning programming it's extremely important to use *proper indentation* as that communicates the structure of your code very clearly. Many simple mistakes that can be time-consuming to fix are often easily avoided by having clean, orderly code.

Comment: Is `+ \n` valid Java?

Comment: Is it the same file after which you want to print the statements?

Comment: @tadman No, the rest looks like java though.  It might be a typo, in which case they should have copied and pasted to avoid errors

Comment: @phflack Alright. Wasn't sure if Java adopted some kind of character literal notation like Ruby's bizarro `?n` notation.

Comment: @melanzane yes same file, need to print the data from that one file multiple times depending on length of array

Comment: @everyone_going_off_topic, original copy was longer so i wrote simplified version and made a typo

Answer (score 1):

I would read the whole file first, store it in memory and do the loop. As @AntonH said the br (I suppose is a BufferReader) gets to end of the file in the while and you don't point it to the beginning  again.

```
String a;
String b = "";          
while (a = br.readLine() ){
    b += a + "\n"
}
for (int i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    fileWriter.write(b + "Hello from "  + arr[i] + "\n");
}
```